How do I get VS Code to recognize directories when importing using python
I'm building and testing some code, but I can only seem to get VS Code to recognize the modules that are in the same directory as the main module. I want to be able to have access to other directories but it is not recognizing them. I end up using:
from module import class

instead I want to use:
from directory.module import class

I have read that I need to change the PYPATH, but I'm pretty new to coding, and really don't want to mess things up, or have to keep adding directory paths every time I work on something new. I have started and activated the virtual environment, as well as made sure that the workspace is the root directory.

Firstly this has nothing to do with VS Code. The import statement is only used by the Python interpreter. But without seeing your project structure and any actual error messages it is rather difficult to provide a useful answer.

Please edit your question and add a directory listing of the contents of your project, the import statements that fail, and the actual error messages generated by Python.
